# TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable Python

Tags: python, machine-learning

Currently coding for some machine learning in which I am using sklearn, numpy and scipy. I am able to parse my database and prepare data-sets. However when coming to prediction and outputting results, I am getting the following error:

*Type Error: 'tuple' object is not callable*

My code is below:

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn import gaussian_process
from sklearn import neural_network
from sklearn import preprocessing
from time import time
import numpy as np

t0 = time()

classifier = int(input(
"""
Enter number corresponding to classifier you would like to use:
1. Support Vector Machines
2. Gaussian Naive Bayes
3. Multinomial Naive Bayes
4. Stochastic Gradient Descent with Logistic Regression loss function
"""))

dataset = int(input(
"""
Enter number corresponding to data set you would like to use:
1. First half and second half
2. Alternating
3. Alternating with attack type
4. Alternating with attack type and target type
"""))

# Assign appropriate datasets
input_files = ['half', 'alternating', 'alternating-with-attacktype', 'alternating-all']
filename = input_files[dataset-1]

# Instantiate arrays for inputs and outputs
train_inputs = []
train_outputs = np.array([])

test_inputs = []
test_expected_outputs = np.array([])
test_actual_outputs = []
X = np.array([])
# Read training file
print ('Reading training file')
t = time()

for line in open('datasets/%s-train.txt' % filename):
    inputs = line.split(' ')
    outputs = inputs.pop()
    train_outputs = np.append(train_outputs, int(outputs))
print ('Done. Time taken: %f secs.\n' % (time()-t))

# for line in open('datasets/%s-train.txt' % filename):
#   inputs = line.split(' ')
#   output = inputs.pop()
#   train_outputs = np.append(train_outputs, int(output))
# print ('Done. Time taken: %f secs.\n' % (time()-t))

print ('Create classifier')
t = time()
clf = None

# No preprocessing for SVMs
# Otherwise, scale inputs (preprocessing to make more amenable for machine learning)
if classifier == 1: # Support vector machines
  clf = SVC()
elif classifier == 2: # Gaussian Naive Bayes
  train_inputs = preprocessing.scale(np.array(train_inputs))
  clf = GaussianNB()
elif classifier == 3: # Multinomial Naive Bayes
  clf = MultinomialNB()
elif classifier == 4: # Stochastic gradient descent with logistic regression
  train_inputs = preprocessing.scale(np.array(train_inputs))
  clf = SGDClassifier(loss='log')
print ('Done. Time taken: %f secs.\n' % (time()-t))

print ('Fit classifier')
t = time()
X.shape(1 -1)
clf.fit(train_inputs, train_outputs)
print ('Done. Time taken: %f secs.\n' % (time()-t))

# Read test file and scale inputs
print ('Reading test file')
t = time()
for line in open('datasets/%s-test.txt' % filename):
  inputs = line.split(' ')
  output = inputs.pop()
  test_expected_outputs = np.append(test_expected_outputs, int(output))
  test_inputs.append(map(float, inputs))

# Same here: no preprocessing for SVMs
# Otherwise, scale inputs (preprocessing to make more amenable for machine learning)
if classifier != 1:
  test_inputs = preprocessing.scale(np.array(test_inputs))
print ('Done. Time taken: %f secs.\n' % (time()-t))

print ('Predict for test file')
t = time()
test_actual_outputs = [clf.predict(i)[0] for i in test_inputs]
print ('Done. Time taken: %f secs.\n' % (time()-t))

print ('Compare outputs')
t = time()
right = sum(test_actual_outputs == test_expected_outputs)
wrong = len(test_actual_outputs) - right
print ('Done. Time taken: %f secs.\n' % (time()-t))

print ('Number right: %d\nNumber wrong: %d' % (right, wrong))
print ('Prediction rate: %.2f%%' % (100.0 * right/len(test_actual_outputs)))
print ('Total time taken: %f secs.\n' % (time()-t0))
```

I know that I need to add array.reshape(-1 1) or array.reshape(1 -1) but not sure what this will do.

Any advice on how to solve this would be welcome.

Comment: Please: a [mcve]. Also you *absolutely* must provide the **full traceback** in your question.

Comment: What's the full traceback so we can see what raises the error without digging through the code?

Comment: 1. this is a long program - try to create a minimal, preferably self contained, example that reproduces the error
2. post the full error message (it's not clear in which line the program fails)
3. try to step in the program with a debugger - it will probably help you understand what the problem is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is coming from the line:

```
X.shape(1 -1)
```

Use `X.shape` instead.

Here's a reproduction of the issue:

```
X = pd.Series()
X.shape(1 -1)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-105-1bb3332dc7d5> in <module>()
      1 X = pd.Series()
----> 2 X.shape(1 -1)

TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```